# C UDP read and recv are breaking my code

Tags: c, sockets, udp, recvfrom

So I'm working with UDP sockets and poll(), trying to be able to wait for connections and read input at the same time, but I'm coming up with the weirdest error and I have no idea how to handle it. Here's the part of my code that's causing issues.

```
int n=1;   //set n =1 so that it can enter first loop

while (1) {
  for(int j = 0; j < 2; j++){
    printf("loop1\n");
    if(n>0){
      printf("loop2\n");
      mlen = read(sd, buf, BSIZE);      
      //I would like to use read here, but I've tried both read and recvfrom
      //and both have the same issue \/ that's the other code I was trying
      //mlen = recvfrom(sd,buf,BSIZE,0,(struct sockaddr *)&cad, &fromlen);
      if(mlen<0){
        perror("recvfrom");
        exit(1);
      }

      /* more code here that does stuff with buffer info */
    }
    else {
      perror("poll");
      exit(1);}
    }
  }
  n = poll(pollarr,2,-1);
  printf("now n is %d\n", n);
}
```

So here's where it gets strange. When I run this code, it prints out loop1, but does not print loop2, even though I explicitly set n=1 at the beginning. I changed the loop1 print statement to "printf("now n is %d\n", n);" to see what was going on, and then it didn't print anything at all.

To add to this mystery, this happens regardless of if I use read or recv, but when I comment out both of those my code enters both loops just fine.

So, somehow both read and recv are preventing my program from running the way it should, before those lines are even reached. I have no clue what could be going on, and my best guess would be that it's some obscure C thing that I just don't know about. Does anyone know what's going wrong?

If it matters, I think I'm using Linux.

Comment: flush the stdout after your print statement `printf("loop2\n");` using `fflush(stdout);`

Comment: @aneeshjose, if that's going to a terminal device, it should be flushed automagically due to the newline. Only if it cannot be detected as an interactive device will it be fully buffered.

Comment: How do you know there’s data to be read?  You need to provide an MCVE ([MCVE]).   And you likely need to provide sender and receiver.

Comment: Does `pollarr` actually point to the beginning of an array of two poll file descriptors? Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as @JonathanLeffler requested.